# Groovy Time Duration returns days but not months

Tags: groovy

Trying to get duration in months between two dates but duration.months returns 0. Only duration.days works. What am I doing wrong?

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def startDate = new Date()

def endDate
def duration

use(TimeCategory) {
    endDate = startDate + 50.days
    duration = endDate - startDate
}

println "$duration.days days but $duration.months months"
```

Output:
50 days but 0 months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many months would you want it to return?  50/30 = 1.66, but that's for 30 day months.

From the docs: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/Duration.html

> Duration represents time periods which have values independent of the
>   context. So, whilst we can't say how long a month is without knowing
>   the year and the name of the month, we know how long a day is
>   independent of the date.

Essentially, Duration objects (which is what date subtraction returns in a TimeCategory) don't know WHEN they are, just how long they are.

Comment: Ah! I missed the "context independent" part of the docs. Makes sense now. Thanks